# Can we add direction parameter

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, youtube-api, react-native-navigation

I'm new to react native and I can't work with these types of problems before.

Can we add a direction parameter in the Google Map places finder URL?

For Example:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${latitude},${longitude}&radius=${radius}&keyword=${keyword}&type=${type}&key=${GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY}](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$%7Blatitude%7D,$%7Blongitude%7D&radius=$%7Bradius%7D&keyword=$%7Bkeyword%7D&type=$%7Btype%7D&key=$%7BGOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY%7D)

This URL requires location, radius, keyword, type, and Google Places API Key.

Can we add a direction parameter in this URL?

I want to add a direction parameter to Google Places finder URL.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you're looking for, but you can add as many url parameters as you want just append to it `&key=value`:

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${latitude},${longitude}&radius=${radius}&keyword=${keyword}&type=${type}&key=${GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY}&direction=${direction}](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$%7Blatitude%7D,$%7Blongitude%7D&radius=$%7Bradius%7D&keyword=$%7Bkeyword%7D&type=$%7Btype%7D&key=$%7BGOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY%7D&direction=$%7Bdirection%7D)